# May I use the word "miscreant" in my thesis?

Tags: nouns, word-usage, slang

I am writing my thesis. May I use the word *miscreant* to refer to people who create viruses to spread them on the Internet? Or is it a slang term that I must avoid?

Comment: This seems perfectly acceptable in my opinion. Miscreant would not be a slang term, and would be understandable by most to mean a "trouble-maker".

Comment: As an aside, "is it an English slang" makes no sense. You can either ask "is it slang", uncountable, or you can ask "is it a slang word".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

**[Miscreant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/miscreant)**: (Noun/adjective) A person who behaves badly or in a way that breaks the law.

> People who create viruses are miscreants.
>
> Miscreant people write viruses to do bad things (like stealing passwords).

---

> Origin:  1350–1400; Middle English  < Middle French mescreant
> (unbelieving), equivalent to mes- mis-  + creant  ≪ Latin crēdent-
> credent

---

It seems quite common use for unethical hackers who are to blame for building malicious code.

Some examples: [This article](http://www.websitedefender.com/web-security/inside-the-mind-of-a-web-miscreant/), [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/05/07/4chan_bounty/) (... The bounty programme was launched after the image-board website and a drawing website, both founded by Chris "moot" Poole, were compromised by **miscreants**.), [here](http://www.democratandchronicle.com/story/news/2014/05/02/monroe-county-center/8621217/) (... But the incident drove home the point yet again that digital technology has enabled a range of computer and telephone scams that seems limited only by the imaginations of the **miscreants** who attempt them...).